# The default folder for a bookmarked page

Tags: bookmarks

My ubuntu 18.04 has usually stored a bookmarked page automatically to the
''Other bookmarks'' folder, but now it goes to another folder. What did I do
wrong and how can I change this back to the ''Other bookmarks'' folder.

Comment: Which browser? How it was installed?

Comment: To what "another folder" does it go? What is the "Other bookmarks" folder"? I do not have that on my system. Or are you indeed referring to a browser and not to the file manager? Please "Edit" your question and clarify.

Comment: If you are talking about Firefox, please take care of the **Location** value in the **Add bookmark** dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Click the menu button 3bars on right side, click bookmarks and then at bottom side **Manage Bookmarks**.

Comment: ..and next? How are new bookmarks automatically be ending up in "Other Bookmarks" again? What browser are you referring to? The default browser Firefox?